# I am wondering if there is a way to show a page within another page as a dialog box or pop up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am wondering if there is a way to show a page within another page as a dialog box or pop up? let's say I have page ( a.shtml ) and I am working in page( b.shtml ) is there a way to pop up page ( a.shtml ) as dialog box within page ( b.shtml )?

Please let me know if my question is not clear and please consider that this is my first question here. Thanks in advance

Comment: are you familiar with iframes? Sound like they could be helpful here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into iframes, depending on what you're trying to do. These are DOM elements that display another URL, and can be sized and controlled using regular CSS or via js: [iframes](http://html.com/tags/iframe/)

Bear in mind that communicating between your page and the iframe may only be possible if they are the same origin: [cross-window communication](https://javascript.info/cross-window-communication)

Comment: Thank you! great stuff out there. And yeah you are right I fixed it after I changed it into a partial and included it in both pages and added a default hide class to for the second page that I want to control it

Answer (score 0):

I believe load() can help you achieve this...
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_load.asp

**HTML:**

```
<div id="pageA"></div>
```

**jQuery/AJAX:**
Assuming the pages are in the same folder...

```
$(function(){ 
  $('#pageA').load('./a.shtml');
});
```

Comment: Thank you iPzard. It wasn't exactly what I wanted but, that helped me to get there and solve it and that's all thanks to you

Comment: No problem, glad to help! :)